# scala main returns unit. How to set program's return value

Tags: scala

The method prototype for [main is](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit
```

Typically, an application needs to specify a return code when it exits. How is that typically done in scala if main returns Unit? Should I call System.exit(n)?

Also, the docs warn that I should not use main at all, though this seems at odds with the [getting started guide](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html)).

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you exit with a code different than zero by calling either `java.lang.System.exit(n)` or better `sys.exit(n)` (which is Scala's equivalent).

If you mix in `App` in your main application object, you do not define method `main` but can just write its contents in the object's body directly.

E.g.

```
object Test extends App {
  val a0 = args.headOption.getOrElse {
    Console.err.println("Need an argument")
    sys.exit(1)
  }
  println("Yo " + a0)
  // implicit: sys.exit(0)
}
```